# Did Einstein say this about philosopher Peter Deunov?

Tags: quotes, albert-einstein

Multiple sources and books about [Peter Deunov](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peter_Deunov) state that Albert Einstein said this:

> "The whole world bows to me, but I bow to the Master Peter Deunov of
>   Bulgaria."

I cannot find any context or the actual source for this quote -- where does it come from?

Comment: I found a thread on reddit that suggests the context was related to how Peter Deunov helped save some Jewish people during WWII.  Might be a good starting point; though it seems like they weren't able to find a good source either.  https://www.reddit.com/r/skeptic/comments/gjs71/hey_skeptics_i_need_a_hand_with_an_einstein_quote/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The earliest citation I can find for this claim is that it came from a 2007 Bulgarian National Television interview with Andrei Griva, a disciple of Deunov. In that interview, Griva stated this statement could be heard in a radio interview with Einstein broadcast by *Radiodiffusion française* in 1989. (see [comment #2 here](http://newspaper.kultura.bg/bg/article/view/18329/3), and [this newspaper story](https://web.archive.org/web/20141019202930/http://www.monitor.bg/article?id=226433) confirming that 1989 is not a typo) However, *[Radiodiffusion française](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radiodiffusion_Fran%C3%A7aise)* ceased to exist in 1949.

More recently, [Einstein expert John Norton](http://newspaper.kultura.bg/bg/article/view/18329/3) said he had never come across the name Deunov in all the writings of Einstein that he knew, and that *"the whole world bows to me"* is not something Einstein would say.

Answer (score 10):

The searchable digital archives of Einstein's papers (which includes not just academic work but also letters, speeches etc) does not contain a document containing Danow (German spelling), Deunov, or Deunoff. If you want you can check other spellings yourself here! https://einsteinpapers.press.princeton.edu/

While it is hard to prove a negative this suggests that the quote is not true. If none of the books cite a source for a quote I would not count them as really reliable sources.